# Stroustrup Calculator produces NaN instead of expected value

Tags: c++, calculator, nan

I am working through Stroustrup's "Programming: Principles and Practice using C++" as a complete beginner, using CodeBlocks 10.05 with GNU GCC compiler. I got stuck on an exercise debugging a calculator program because any numerical input would end up as NaN. I tried his solution located [here](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/Solutions/Ch7/e7-1.cpp), with [this header](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/std_lib_facilities.h), and found that it produces the same result - for example, entering the following (`;` used to print result):

> 2.2;

produces output:

> = nan

Running the same code compiled with Visual Studio 2010 produced a program that gives the expected output:

> = 2.2

I reduced and modified the program to test the calculator's primary() function with a fixed input, and found that if the following two lines are commented out, CodeBlocks produces the expected output; if not, the output is =nan. What's causing this to happen?

```
#include "../std_lib_facilities.h"

class Token {
    public:
    char kind;        
    double value;     
    //string name;          
    Token(char ch)    
        :kind(ch), value(0) { }
    Token(char ch, double val)     
        :kind(ch), value(val) { }
    //Token(char ch, string n) :kind(ch), name(n) { }
};


const char number='8';

double primary()
{
    Token t = Token(number,2.2);
    switch (t.kind) {

    case number:
        return t.value;
    default:
        error("primary expected");
    }
}

int main()
{
    cout<<primary();
}
```

Comment: This is (minor?) problem but your program reaches the point when function declared to return double returns void, add `return 0;` after `error()` or after whole `switch` block. Compiler should print a warning or to about that. Hope you're using `-Wall`

Comment: What version of GCC is being used with CodeBlocks 10.05?  Did you copy the posted program using the clipboard?  I see not problems with it, and get `2.2` for output with both GCC (MinGW 4.6.1) and MSVC 16.  Both with an without optimizations.

Comment: @Vyktor: I'd guess that `error()` never returns and aborts the program.

Comment: @MichaelBurr yeah, I'm guessing that too... But still, compiler should report that as an warning, shouldn't it? (Something about control reached void in nonvoid function or so)... and I personally prefer writing those as: `switch(){case, case, case, default only if it sets value} error( "...");return -1;` You cannot be sure that noone will redefine your error function when he/she reuses your codes and it just seem as a good practice to me to put it this way + having `exit;return` explicitly at the end of the function, just before braces increases readability (IMHO).

Comment: @Vyktor: not unless `error` is tagged with `__attribute__((noreturn))`.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: I was using GCC 4.4.1 - switched to 4.6.1 and it's working. If you want to submit that as the answer please do :) Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is the exact compile command line (all options). What is the output of ldd on the resulting executable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue with GCC 4.4.1. Program compiled with GCC 4.6.1 produced the correct output.

Answer (score 0):

We are having to guess about the actual types (string, error). However, it strikes me as *wrong* that you fail to initialize all class members in all constructors. Try this:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

static void error(const std::string& s)
{
    std::cerr << "Error: " << s << "\n";
    std::terminate();
}

class Token {
    public:
        char kind;        
        double value;     
        std::string name;          
        Token(char ch)    
            :kind(ch), value(0), name() { }
        Token(char ch, double val)     
            :kind(ch), value(val), name() { }
        Token(char ch, std::string n) :kind(ch), value(0), name(n) { }
};


const char number='8';

double primary()
{
    Token t = Token(number,2.2);
    switch (t.kind) {

        case number:
            return t.value;
        default:
            error("primary expected");
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::cout<<primary();
}
```

Comment: `string` is simply `std::string` pulled in by `std_lib_facilities.h` (which has a `using namespace std;`).

Comment: @MichaelBurr: You just made me cringe :x

Comment: @PeteKirkham: Dear Mr. Kirkham; I'm afraid you missed the point. The problem wasn't with the `name` field, it was with the missing initializer for `value`. You know, that same field that was being displayed as `NaN`? As you are probably well aware, these types are **not** zero-initialized/default constructed automatically. _I merely listed the `name` initializer too, for completeness and because it is a good habit. At this level, I think it doesn't help to explain why the one works and the other doesn't._

Comment: This program produced the same =nan output. I was using GCC 4.4.1, which was bundled with CodeBlocks - switched to GCC 4.6.1 and got the expected =2.2 with both your code and mine. Thanks, and appreciate the pointer about member initialization.

Comment: @concrete_d: ok, surprising. I have just tried with a wide variety of versions (gcc 4.3.5, 4.4.5, 4.5.2, 4.6.1, 4.7 unstable; 32bit, 64bit, -O0..4 -fomit-frame-pointer) and running it under valgrind, found no inconsistencies. You should really look at upgrading your GCC; I'm afraid reporting a compiler bug won't help you since it is an old version. No doubt, it has already been fixed

Comment: A conforming compiler won't call the constructor which does not initialise the value member, therefore not initialising that member if name is given is not the bug; it is possibly wrong that the code doesn't initialise value if name is given, but without knowing the rest of the code it only becomes undefined if something reads the value, and it may have been intentional (e.g. depending on the value of `kind` either `name` or `value` is expected to be used). So the problem is that the compiler is picking up the wrong overload, not that some members are not explicitly initialised.

Comment: @PeteKirkham I know that too. However, that is a far cry from your initial claim `"It is not remotely wrong"`, I'd appreciate if you would be so nice as to drop that comment. I will clean up my side of the comment thread too.